Purpose of bolts/hinge on side of bolt cutters
What is the purpose of the bolts and hinge on the side of these bolt cutters?



Those are stops for travel and alignment adjustment. One helps keep the jaws parallel when closed. One provides a bumper so the jaws aren't overtightened and dulled.
Learn how it's done
